# Different definitions of derivate

Tags: calculus, derivatives

First, the definition of derivative is that the derivative is an operator that allows one to calculate the angular coefficient of the tangent line passing through the point of the function (here I understand) and the second definition  from Wikipedia is that the derivative is the rate of change with respect to subject ... but in what sense? Because the derivative, for example, evaluates how distance s changes over time t. What does it have to do with the angular coefficient etc ?? Is it serious if I am not immediately understanding the definition of derivative?

Answer (score 0):

For some function $f(x)$ the graph of the function $(x,f(x))$ or $y = f(x).$  The slope of any secant between two points on the curve is $\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} = m$, and as the secant gets short, we say that the slope of the tangent line is $\frac {dy}{dx}$

We can then use this slope to find an equation of the tangent line at a point on the curve $(x_0,y_0)$ is $(y-y_0) = \frac {dy}{dx}(x-x_0)$  And this is the best linear approximation of the function.

And so a small change in $x$ will result in a proportional change in $y$.  $(y-y_0) = \Delta y$ and $(x-x_0) = \Delta x$ and so

$\Delta y \approx \frac {dy}{dx} \Delta x$

Or $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is our best measurement of the sensitivity of a function $y$ to a small change in $x.$

In physics, were we are frequently using function that depend on time, as the interval of time approaches zero, it would be accurate do describe this as instantaneous, and the derivative as the instantaneous rate of change.

Comment: I dont understand, why measurement of the sensivity of a function? What does mean?

Comment: How much does the output change, related to a change in the inputs.